# How to get Redshift external table id?

Tags: amazon-redshift

I tried to get redshift external table id but failed.

`select c.oid,c.* from SVV_EXTERNAL_TABLES c;`

For common tables I have this value.

`select c.oid,c.* from pg_class c`